# IntelliJ doesn't recognize Kotlin JPA plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot project setup with Kotlin and Gradle in IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.3.2. I included the Kotlin JPA plugin in my `build.gradle.kts` so no-args constructors will be autogenerated for `Entities`. This all works fine when I run `bootRun` from Gradle.

IntelliJ doesn't recognize that the JPA plugin is installed though. It gives the below error as I'm developing (note that everything compiles and works fine at runtime, its just this error in IntelliJ that I'm trying to get rid of):

[image]

The thing is, IntelliJ recognizes I have the plugin installed as can be seen below in my project's facets (next to the `org.jetbrains.kotlin.noarg` entry), but it still shows the error above. I checked inspections to see if I can disable the inspection but there isn't one for this error. How can I get IntelliJ to recognize that my `Entity` classes are fine?

[image]

Comment: This happens from time to time, usually either a restart or a invalidate caches + restart helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to update Kotlin from 1.3.61 to 1.3.70-eap-274. And feel free to vote or comment on a similar issue in Kotlin public tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36964. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Sergei, I'm the author of that issue. I updated my Kotlin plugin in IntelliJ to 1.3.70-eap-274 as per Margarita's comment and it fixed the issue.